# Transfer files between Shared Hosting servers using FTPES

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, ftps, ftpes

I have two shared hosting servers and a VPS. One at ixwebhostings with their panel and other is a cPanel hosting. I would like to move some files between these two. ixwebhosting supports FTP and cPanel supports FTPES only. and i have full root access to my VPS. Whats the best way to transfer files in between these shared hosting?

I have tried like this

1. connect to FTP using 'mc' from my VPS and transferred all files to the VPS. But i couldn't connect with Midnight commander to the cPanel, FTPES only hosting.
2. Transfer all files from FTP server to my personal computer and transfer to the FTPES server using filezilla.

Is there any terminal supporting file managers with FTPES support?

Comment: yea its FTPS. FTPES is FTPS in explicit mode

Answer (score 0):

I am using `lftp` for any FTP things. If you want to embed in scripts, then you can use `curl` too.